# Is a javascript object's toString function affected by localisation?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

This might be a **very** silly question, but can I rely on the toString() function regardless of the language settings of a client?

That is, for me:

```
x = true;
x.toString();  // "true"
```

If someone from France ran my application, would the output be `"true"` or `"vrai"`?

Comment: localization in the browser doesn't automatically translate the page ... so no.

Comment: Well, local settings do affect other things, such as time zones, so I thought I'd double-check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For booleans, a conforming ECMAScript interpreter *must* convert `true` to `"true"` and `false` to `"false"` [(§9.8 and §15.6.4.2)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Yes your following example will run regardless of localisation.

Comment: meaning that x.toString() will always result to "true" in this case.

Answer (score 3):

When invoking `.toString()` on a boolean, you always get `"true"` or `"false"`. See the [ECMA-262 documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), paragraph 15.6.4.2.

For other types like numbers and dates, you have two methods: `toString()` and `toLocaleString()`.